# Настройка нескольких логов доступа в Apache 2.4

Tags: логирование, request, apache2.4, директива

Хочу писать дополнительный логи по ботам (запросам к robots.txt) и реферерам (запросы с непустым реферером не на моем сайте). А также отключить запись в лог некоторых служебных запросов.
Для этого в настройках вирт. хоста пишу:

```
<IfModule mod_log_config.c>
  LogFormat "%a %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" \"%q\" UM=%{UM}C" combined+
  LogFormat "%t %a \"%r\" \"%U\" \"%q\" %>s \"%{Referer}i\" UM=%{UM}C" referer+
  LogFormat "%t %a \"%r\" %>s \"%{User-Agent}i\"" bot+

  # requests for the robots.txt file
  SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/robots\.txt$" is_bot
  CustomLog "/logs/bot_log" bot+ env=is_bot

  # empty referers
  SetEnvIf Referer "^$" no_referer
  # referers on our site (oursite.ru)
  SetEnvIf Referer ".*oursite\.ru.*" no_referer
  # service requests
  SetEnvIf Request_URI ".*/img/.*" no_referer, no_log
  SetEnvIf Request_URI ".*/css/.*" no_referer, no_log
  SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/favicon\.ico$" no_referer, no_log
  CustomLog "/logs/referer_log" referer+ env=!no_referer

  ErrorLog "/logs/error_log"
  CustomLog "/logs/access_log" combined+ env=!no_log
</IfModule>
```

В результате пишется всё, кроме bot_log (похоже, условие `SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/robots\.txt$" is_bot` не работает). 
При этом запросы к robots.txt пишутся в access_log, но почему-то в другом формате (не `combined+` и не `bot+`).

Никак не пойму: в чём причина? И что не так в настройках?

P.S. Обратил внимание, что robots.txt запрашивается по протоколу HTTP/1.1, а не HTTP/1.0. Может быть, в этом причина?